# Styling Pandas Code Looping Twice and Doubling Running Time of Bot

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop, dataframe, styling

My styling pandas code is looping twice and doubling the running time of my Program. Please help me figure out why?

I am creating a bot that scrapes a website for certain strings and colors the dataframe cell containing that website's URL based on the results. This is done using the Styling feature for Pandas. The output and the code that produces it look as follows:

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hCh4.png)

```
#defining colour function. 'site' is variable that stores element in 'Article URL' cell.
def A_4thStreetWine_func(site):

    site_download = rq.get(site)          

    #convert website to string and look for specified strings in it. returns Boolean.  
    condition_1 = '4th' in site_download.text \
                  and 'Street' in site_download.text \
                  and 'Project Runway'in site_download.text \
                  or  '4th' in site_download.text \
                  and 'STREET' in site_download.text \
                  and 'Project Runway'in site_download.text 

    print(condition_1)

    condition_2 =       "403 Forbidden" in site_download.text
    condition_3 =       "Page not found" in site_download.text

    if condition_1:
                 color = 'green'
    elif condition_2:
                color = 'orange'
    elif condition_3:
                color = 'purple'
    else:
                 color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

#colour 'Article URL' cells in rows 329 and 351 according to function. 'A_4thStreetWine_DF' is key of dataframe in dataframe dictionary (dfd).    
dfd['A_4thStreetWine_DF'].loc[[329,351]].style.applymap(A_4thStreetWine_func, subset=['Article URL'])
```

The style.applymap() method causes the function to loop through the specified cells in the dataframe, checking each URL and coloring its cell. However, when I print (condition_1), it becomes apparent that it is checking each website twice and literally doubling the running time of the program.

[Code Output With Condition Printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfurC.png)

Can someone help me figure out why that is and how to make the loop run once?